# How do i center all items in a weighted Row/Column?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Row that displays images in a 1:1 ratio like this:

```
Row(Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
    Image(..., Modifier.aspectRatio(1f, true).weight(1f))
    Image(..., Modifier.aspectRatio(1f, true).weight(1f))
    Image(..., Modifier.aspectRatio(1f, true).weight(1f))
}
```

I would like to show these images as big as possible and in the center of the row. If the width or the height of the row is smaller than all images should be scaled down to the same size in order to fit into the row again.

When I use this code with the `.weight(1f)` modifier it almost works. However the space between the images is equally distributed, so they are not centered.

Comment: Can you add an image of what you want and what you have at the moment? The requirement is not clear. The code seems to work as per the given requirement for me from what I understand.

Comment: You can use `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center` , did you try that?